# org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: Element <a class="bg-inverse "> could not be scrolled into view when trying to click a button

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, geckodriver

I'm working with gecko driver selenium java with FF 60.0. Previously my code was working properly, but all of sudden, now every time I run it, it gives me an error as `could not be scrolled into view` while I'm trying to click a button.
below is my code, I tried with `Thread.sleep(5000)` or implicit wait but nothing is working.I'm stuck here.

```
public void goToWorkerSummary() throws InterruptedException {
    WebElement btnWorkerSummary = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='/admin/worker-summary']"));
    //Thread.sleep(5000);//wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(btnWorkerSummary).click();
    btnWorkerSummary.click();
}
```

the Code up to this points works but as soon as it reaches here, it is showing the above error.
below is the error snippet.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: Element <a class="bg-inverse text-white dropdown-item" href="/admin/worker-summary"> could not be scrolled into view
Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T15:15:03.216Z'
System info: host: 'CPU-38', ip: '192.168.0.55', os.name: 'Windows 8', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.2', java.version: '1.8.0_51'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, browserVersion: 60.0.2, javascriptEnabled: true, moz:accessibilityChecks: false, moz:headless: false, moz:processID: 2480, moz:profile: C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Lo..., moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin: false, moz:webdriverClick: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, platformVersion: 6.2, rotatable: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}}
Session ID: 08c08933-06f6-480c-88c9-9d7ab718c2c8
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:276)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:83)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: Element <a class="bg-inverse text-white dropdown-item" href="/admin/worker-summary"> could not be scrolled into view
```

...implies that the *GeckoDriver* / *FirefoxDriver* was unable to interact with the desired element.

### Solution

Once you locate the element **btnWorkerSummary** moving ahead as you are invoking **`click()`** instead of *ExpectedConditions* as `visibilityOf` you need to use [**`elementToBeClickable()`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#elementToBeClickable-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-) as follows:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@href='/admin/worker-summary']"))).click();
```

---

However, another issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- Your *Selenium Client* version is **3.12.0**.
- Your *JDK* version is **1.8.0_51** which is **ancient**.

### Solution

- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [JDK 8u201](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).
- Execute your `@Test`.

Comment: though, I updated JDK,thanks for the suggestion, but I figured out that problem is with xpath, updated my xpath and it got fixed by using elementToBeClickable()

Answer (score 1):

Try to use javascriptexecutor as shown sample code below,

```
JavascriptExecutor je = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
je.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='/admin/worker-summary']")));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try following js to scroll the page.Enter Pixel asper your requirement to scroll page. Here I use 3000 Px to scroll page to mid

```html
   JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,3000)");
```