# Selenium python Error: element could not be scrolled into view

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, firefox, webdriverwait, geckodriver

I am working on automating the IdentiGO application for my company, and I'm getting the following error:

```
Internal Server Error: /identigo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jane/Code/maynard_env/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/jane/Code/maynard_env/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/jane/Code/maynard_env/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/jane/Code/maynard_env/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jane/Code/maynard_env/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jane/Code/maynard_env/maynard/employee/views.py", line 63, in post
    driver.main(employee)
  File "/Users/jane/Code/maynard_env/maynard/employee/driver.py", line 31, in main
    WebDriverWait(driver, 1000000).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[5]/div[3]/div/button/span'))).click()
  File "/Users/jane/Code/maynard_env/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "/Users/jane/Code/maynard_env/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/Users/jane/Code/maynard_env/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Users/jane/Code/maynard_env/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <span class="ui-button-text"> could not be scrolled into view
```

Here is my code, with the scripts leading up to this page omitted since they aren't relevant to my problem.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


WebDriverWait(driver, 1000000).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[5]/div[3]/div/button/span'))).click()
```

> On the page prior to this code, where the user selects an appointment date and time; I want the script to wait for the "Go" button to be pushed, then click on "Continue" in the following screenshot:

[image]

If you would like to see the exact page, go to [this](https://tn.ibtfingerprint.com/) url, then you will have to make a series of POST requests using the following info:

- click schedule a new appointment
- other
- vendors and contractors (children)
- tnvc00047
- 37204
- make random appointment date

Any advice would really be appreciated!

### Update

Here is a JS Fiddle with the html of the page:

https://jsfiddle.net/khf4tym3/

When I click "view page source", the popup html doesn't show in the source code, so I assume that it is generated with JS.

```html
<div class="ui-dialog-buttonset">
    <button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
        <span class="ui-button-text">Continue</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

### Update 2

If I change the line `WebDriverWait(driver, 1000000)` to `WebDriverWait(driver, 30)`, I get the following error instead:

```
Internal Server Error: /identigo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jane/Code/maynard_env/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/jane/Code/maynard_env/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/jane/Code/maynard_env/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/jane/Code/maynard_env/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jane/Code/maynard_env/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jane/Code/maynard_env/maynard/employee/views.py", line 63, in post
    driver.main(employee)
  File "/Users/jane/Code/maynard_env/maynard/employee/driver.py", line 34, in main
    element=WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='ui-dialog-buttonset']/button[@class='ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only']/span[contains(.,'Continue')]")))
  File "/Users/jane/Code/maynard_env/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

### pythonfiddle

code for the project so far, so you can skip the forum entry.

https://jsfiddle.net/93k5s2xg/1/

The working solution:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[starts-with(@aria-describedby, 'ui-id-')]//span[@class='ui-button-text' and text()='Continue']"))).click()
```

Comment: can you post the html of that alert?

Comment: Either you have to share the html or the correct tvnc.

Comment: @CalebGoodman : sorry i haven't seen your message.just check..give me some time i'll get back you

Comment: Let me know how it goes.I have tested on chrome browser.If you want I can share you complete code tomorrow which work fine on my windows laptop.

Comment: @KunduK I added another bounty to make it worth your time.

Comment: The code I have posted yesterday isn’t working?

Comment: @CalebGoodman : Have you tested my yesterdays posted code?

Comment: @CalebGoodman : Try the last code block.It is working fine with chrome browser and win 10 OS.I have run the code at least 10 times.

Comment: @CalebGoodman `//div[starts-with(@aria-describedby, 'ui-id-')]//span[@class='ui-button-text' and text()='Continue']` that was definitely my **toy** :)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <span class="ui-button-text"> could not be scrolled into view
```

...implies that the **WebDriver** instance i.e. *driver* was unable to scroll the element within the [Viewport](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp) to invoke `click()`.

---

First of all, as your usecase is to invoke `click()` on the element, ideally instead of using `presence_of_element_located()` you need to use the *ExpectedConditions* as **`element_to_be_clickable()`** as follows:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 1000000).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[5]/div[3]/div/button/span'))).click()
```

You can find a couple of detailed discussions in:

- [Message: Element  could not be scrolled into view while trying to click on an option within a dropdown menu through Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51250668/message-element-option-could-not-be-scrolled-into-view-while-trying-to-click/51252175#51252175)
- [org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: Element  could not be scrolled into view when trying to click a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51025144/org-openqa-selenium-elementnotinteractableexception-element-a-class-bg-invers/51025869#51025869)

---

As an alternative, as per the error message, to scroll an element within the **Viewport** before invoking `click()` you can also use the [Element.scrollIntoView()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) method.

You can find a detailed discussion in:
- [What is the difference between the different scroll options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54681172/what-is-the-difference-between-the-different-scroll-options/54689339#54689339)

---

At this point it is worth to mention, the following methods:

- [move_to_element()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html#selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains.move_to_element) from [selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains)
- [element_to_be_clickable()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable) from [selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions)

will automatically **scroll** the element within the *Viewport*.

You can find a detailed discussion in:
- [How to scroll a webpage using selenium webdriver in Python without using javascript method execute_script()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55361795/how-to-scroll-a-webpage-using-selenium-webdriver-in-python-without-using-javascr/55587059#55587059)

---

### This usecase

The button with text as **Continue** is within the *Top Level Content* but rendered within a *Modal Dialog Box*.

DevTools Snapshot:

[image: ModalDialogBox]

As the desired element is within a *Modal Dialog Box*, so to locate and invoke `click()` on the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[starts-with(@aria-describedby, 'ui-id-')]//span[@class='ui-button-text' and text()='Continue']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

DevTools Snapshot:

[image: XPath]

Answer (score 11):

Use the following xpath and click on that.

```
element=WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='ui-dialog-buttonset']/button[@class='ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only']/span[contains(.,'Continue')]")))
element.click()
```

If above click not work then try below one.

```
element=WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='ui-dialog-buttonset']/button[@class='ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only']/span[contains(.,'Continue')]")))
element.location_once_scrolled_into_view
element.click()
```

or you can use javascripts executor to click.

```
element=WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='ui-dialog-buttonset']/button[@class='ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only']/span[contains(.,'Continue')]")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

**`EDITED`**

Try the below code it is clicking on continue button where both continue and cancel button there.once you click on continue you will another continue button to click.The code i have updated from schedule app.

```
#Schedule appointment
ele1=WebDriverWait(driver,40).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'(//button[@class="jquiButton ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only"]/span[contains(.,"Schedule")])[1]')))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",ele1)
#click on continue button
WebDriverWait(driver,40).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//button[@class="twoButton continueButton ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only"]/span[contains(.,"Continue")]'))).click()
#click on second continue button
WebDriverWait(driver,40).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//button[@class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only"]/span[contains(.,"Continue")]'))).click()
```

**EDITED Rest of the code.**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
import time

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://tn.ibtfingerprint.com/")
driver.maximize_window()
WebDriverWait(driver,40).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//button[@name="IN_PublicMenuSelection"]/span[contains(.,"Schedule a New Appointment")]'))).click()
time.sleep(5)
select=Select(driver.find_element_by_id("varAgency"))
select.select_by_value("OTHR")
WebDriverWait(driver,40).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//button[@id="collectAgency"]/span[contains(.,"Go")]'))).click()
element=WebDriverWait(driver,40).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,'varAppType')))
select=Select(element)
select.select_by_value("60")
WebDriverWait(driver,40).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//button[@id="collectAppType"][contains(.,"Go")]'))).click()
time.sleep(10)

driver.find_element_by_id("varORI").send_keys("tnvc00047")
WebDriverWait(driver,40).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//button[@id="collectORI"][contains(.,"Go")]'))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,40).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//button[@class="twoButton continueButton ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only"]/span[contains(.,"yes")]'))).click()

elements=WebDriverWait(driver,40).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,'(//i[@class="icon checkbox fa fa-fw fa-square-o fa-2x"])[last()]')))
if(len(elements)>0):
   element=driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//div[@class="fieldentity"]//i[@class="icon checkbox fa fa-fw fa-square-o fa-2x"])[last()]')
   element.location_once_scrolled_into_view
   ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).click().perform()
   elements[0].click()
   driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.fieldentity div").click()
   driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",element)
   element1=WebDriverWait(driver, 40).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//button[@class="jquiButton ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only"]/span[contains(.,"Go")]')))
   driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element1)

time.sleep(10)
driver.find_element_by_name("IN_varLocZipCode").send_keys("37204")
WebDriverWait(driver,40).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//button[@class="jquiButton ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only"]/span[contains(.,"Go")]'))).click()
ele1=WebDriverWait(driver,40).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'(//button[@class="jquiButton ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only"]/span[contains(.,"Schedule")])[1]')))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",ele1)
time.sleep(10)
WebDriverWait(driver,40).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//button[@class="twoButton continueButton ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only"]/span[contains(.,"Continue")]'))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,40).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//button[@class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only"]/span[contains(.,"Continue")]'))).click()
```

---

This Code is working fine on chrome browser and windows 10 OS.I have tested couple of times.

---

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select


driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://tn.ibtfingerprint.com/")
driver.maximize_window()
WebDriverWait(driver,40).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//button[@name="IN_PublicMenuSelection"]/span[contains(.,"Schedule a New Appointment")]'))).click()
element=WebDriverWait(driver,40).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,'varAgency')))
select=Select(element)
select.select_by_value("OTHR")
WebDriverWait(driver,40).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//button[@id="collectAgency"]/span[contains(.,"Go")]'))).click()
element=WebDriverWait(driver,40).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,'varAppType')))
select=Select(element)
select.select_by_value("60")
WebDriverWait(driver,40).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//button[@id="collectAppType"][contains(.,"Go")]'))).click()

WebDriverWait(driver,40).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,'varORI'))).send_keys("tnvc00047")

WebDriverWait(driver,40).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//button[@id="collectORI"][contains(.,"Go")]'))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,40).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//button[@class="twoButton continueButton ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only"]/span[contains(.,"yes")]'))).click()


elements=WebDriverWait(driver,40).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,'(//form[@id="cjisAcknowledgementForm"]//div[@class="fieldentity"]//i[@class="icon checkbox fa fa-fw fa-square-o fa-2x"])[last()]')))

if(len(elements)>0):
   element=driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//form[@id="cjisAcknowledgementForm"]//div[@class="fieldentity"]//i[@class="icon checkbox fa fa-fw fa-square-o fa-2x"])[last()]')
   driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",element)
   element1=WebDriverWait(driver, 40).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//button[@class="jquiButton ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only"]/span[contains(.,"Go")]')))
   driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element1)

WebDriverWait(driver,40).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME,'IN_varLocZipCode'))).send_keys("37204")

WebDriverWait(driver,40).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//button[@class="jquiButton ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only"]/span[contains(.,"Go")]'))).click()
ele1=WebDriverWait(driver,40).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'(//button[@class="jquiButton ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only"]/span[contains(.,"Schedule")])[1]')))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",ele1)

WebDriverWait(driver,40).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//button[@class="twoButton continueButton ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only"]/span[contains(.,"Continue")]'))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,40).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//button[@class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only"]/span[contains(.,"Continue")]'))).click()
```

Comment: I'm getting the `selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:` error with each of these.  I added an update with the full traceback.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you check if there any iframe available on that html page you have posted ?

Comment: I checked in inspector and couldn't find any.

Comment: Ok use your xpath and use the 2nd or 3rd option to check that wether it works?

Comment: I tried using my xpath and I still get the `TimeoutException`.  When I set the wait time to 30, I get a timeout, and when I set it to 10,000 I get the original error message.

Comment: Strange indeed.the html you have posted is matched with xpath I have provided.Only thing I suspect if there any iframe.However you have said there is no iframe on that page.I’ll give it a try later.However the number tvnc00047 is showing invalid don’t know why.

Comment: strange that the ori number isn't working for you, since I just confirmed that it works for me.  I'm guessing the site is blocking your IP since you aren't in Tennessee (I assume).

Comment: Possibly.since you have posted the button element html However can you take the html of entire page and share us as link so that can review the entire html page if possible?

Comment: I added a JS Fiddle in an update.  Also, I'm currently looking for the JS file that inserts the "Continue" button.

Comment: You have provided the wrong html mate.I had ask for the html where continue button present

Comment: When I click "view page source" the Continue button doesn't show up.  I'm not sure how to copy the entire html file with the continue button present.

Comment: How did you post the html of the button element earlier that way you can post entire page

Comment: I copied it from the inspector window

Comment: @CalebGoodman : try the Edited option now i have tested on chrome browser and it is working fine on pc.

Comment: The `ele1` part of the script is trying to make an appointment for a time that is no longer valid, so I can't see if the end of your code is working.  Also, I don't want that part of the script to be automated.  The employee will need to pick a date and time.

Comment: If I remove the 3 lines with `ele1`, the last two lines give me a timeout error.

Comment: Sorry I think I have misunderstood your problem since day 1.I though after click on any appointment you are not able to click on continue button so I provided the code.

Comment: sorry about that :/

Comment: Give me sometime i'll revert.

Comment: I finally got it!  Thanks for your help

Comment: Sorry about that.However to checking at element this should work `WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[contains(@class,'ui-button')]/span[contains(.,'Continue')]"))).click()`

Answer (score 2):

In case someone still has the issue, I fixed it by setting a window size. Example in Java: `driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(5120, 2880));`.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this problem I just add this line in my WebDriverManager class for all tests :

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in Perl and solved it by doing:

```
$element->execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();");
sleep 2;
$element->click();
```