# How to accept cookies popup with Selenium in Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to get past the cookie banner of this site "https://account.bitpanda.com/login" but all solutions I found are not working. The is my current code snippet:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://web.bitpanda.com/price/ltc")#put here the adress of your page

driver.implicitly_wait(4)
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/bpc-cookie-banner")[0].click()
```

I get the following Error:

```
ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <bpc-cookie-banner> could not be scrolled into view
```

And i tried everything stated on this page to resolve this error:

[Selenium python Error: element could not be scrolled into view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56085152/selenium-python-error-element-could-not-be-scrolled-into-view)

But it results only in empty error messages. Somehow I also can't access the button directly as it is somehow hidden within this cookie banner. Has anyone an idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37384458/how-to-handle-elements-inside-shadow-dom-from-selenium  Your elements are in a shadow root.

Comment: The correct answer is already suggested.

Comment: Thank you, that was it.