# How to click on link with text See more anyway using Selenium in Python?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriver, webdriverwait

When using Selenium I tried to scroll down the page but I don't know how to click on the link with text ***See more anyway***.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the url a public url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click on the element with text ***See more anyway*** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) which automatically [scrolls the element within view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56361554/7429447) and you can use the following [*locator strategy*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(., 'The rest of the results')]//span[contains(., 'See more anyway')]"))).click()
  ```
- Or simply:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(., 'See more anyway')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: for my question the URL is 'https://www.google.com/search?q=aircrafts+jongle&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS985US986&sxsrf=ALiCzsYbdeL-qTiWpKJjzeWFvdclyE9CNA:1658590199885&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiYosT9qY_5AhVspIkEHUewB4AQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1536&bih=746&dpr=1.25' .  using your code I got error. I think this is because there is not any button. could you please let me know how to fix it. Do I have to edit anythings?

Comment: the error is InvalidSelectorException .

Comment: I updated my question with new images I think it makes my question clear.

Comment: Checkout the updated answer and let me know the result.