# How do I use Selenium to click this big button?

Tags: python, selenium

I've tried using the elements linktext, value and xpath. I cant seem to make it click on the button with anything. What am I doing wrong?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

PATH = "C:/Users/yongs/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://ttsfree.com/")

textbox = driver.find_element("id", "input_text")
textbox.send_keys("Text to convert")

driver.implicitly_wait(5)


button_xpath = "/html/body/section[2]/div[2]/form/div[2]/div[2]/a"
button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, button_xpath)))

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.click(button)
actions.perform()
```

Comment: What exactly is output of what you already tried? Why doesnt it click on the button, is there any error or warning?

Comment: Why are you using `ActionChains`?

Comment: "Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled" but I doubt is has anything to do with it

Comment: I am using ActionChains, because it would give me this error if I don't "selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <a class="btn mb-2 lg action-1 text-white convert-now" href="#start" title="Convert now">...</a> is not clickable at point (1128, 917). Other element would receive the click: <div height="1239" class="qc-cmp-cleanslate css-vsw46s">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=103.0.5060.134)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDITED to include download solution as well

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.relative_locator import locate_with
import time as t


chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
# chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")


webdriver_service = Service("chromedriver/chromedriver") ## path to where you saved chromedriver binary
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)

url = 'https://ttsfree.com/'

browser.get(url)


WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button/span[text()='AGREE']"))).click()
textbox = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "input_text")))

textbox.send_keys("Text to convert")
button = WebDriverWait(browser, 2000).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='Convert Now']")))
button.click()
print('clicked!')
t.sleep(10)

browser.execute_script('document.getElementsByClassName("label_process text-left")[0].scrollIntoView();')

dl_button = WebDriverWait(browser, 2000).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "fa-download")))
dl_button.click()
t.sleep(10)
browser.quit()
```

Comment: I realize my code has more than one thing wrong, but how did you find the XPath for the button?

Comment: I just used the text content of that button (well, 'a', not 'button') and used it as a selector.

Comment: I'm new to both python and selenium, so I unfortunately do not understand what you mean by 'a' and using it as a selector. Is it possible to use "href" element as a locator? I am having trouble figuring out how to click "Save MP3" button, but I might figure it out once I figure out how you found the XPath for the other button.

Comment: That element's tag is not `<button>`, is `<a>`. Yes, you can use `'href'` as a locator as well if you want. For 'Save MP3' - inspect the element, try to apply the same method I applied for locating 'Convert Now' element.. and if you fail, then ask for help.

Comment: I've tried a couple of things, but I honestly can not figure it out. All the locators for the element seem to change according to input.

Comment: My solution works, using the text content locator.

Comment: I tried this, but the button has a changing text "Save Mp3 (*Kb)" `button = WebDriverWait(browser, 2000).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='Save Mp3']")))`

Comment: @poopylooper - check now...

Comment: That worked. I also tried (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "btn-success") which also worked

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element <kbd>Convert Now</kbd> you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) which automatically [scrolls the element within view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56361554/7429447) and you can use the following [*locator strategy*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *LINK_TEXT*:

  ```
  driver.execute("get", {'url': 'https://ttsfree.com/'})
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "textarea#input_text"))).send_keys("Hello")  
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Convert Now"))).click()
  ```
- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.execute("get", {'url': 'https://ttsfree.com/'})
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "textarea#input_text"))).send_keys("Hello")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.convert-now"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.execute("get", {'url': 'https://ttsfree.com/'})
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "textarea#input_text"))).send_keys("Hello")  
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='Convert Now']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```